# Eclipse PDT - way to close files by doubleclick

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

is there a way how to define how files can be closed in Eclipse. For example, to define that files can be closed by double clicking on file tab.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't change what happens when you double click on the tab - it always maximises.

You can change the key binding for Close in the Preferences (General > Keys).

You can also close by using 'File > Close', or right clicking on the file tab and selecting 'Close', or clicking the 'X' on the tab.